# SQL-Server - Stop success message when saving results to file

Tags: sql-server

When running a query on `SQL Server` and using `Results to file` function, `SQL Server` automatically adds a success message at the end of the file that looks like this:

```
(2620182 row(s) affected)
```

With a small file, you could pop it open a text editor and remove it manually, but when your file is millions of records, it takes a bit more work.  I could use `grep` or `sed` to remove it, but that's a manual process.

Is there a way I can surpress that message from showing up in my saved result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

[`SET NOCOUNT ON;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

before executing your query.

Answer (score 0):

Preceed your Query with `SET NOCOUNT ON`  as shown below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON    
/* Your SQL Query */
```